# XNA Deferred + Forward, Depth Problem?

Tags: xna, c#, hlsl

Im working with my deferred engine in XNA 4.0 and Im combining it with a forwardpipeline to support semi-transparency and other "forward only" effects.

Let me describe what I do:

1. Render GBuffer and all deferred geometry based on materials
2. A final composit where I combine the lightbuffer and the diffusebuffer
   from the GBuffer. I output color and depth to a rendertarget so I
   can use forward rendering to draw directly onto that RT.
3. Render forward geometry
4. I then take the RT from the forward pipeline and do postprocessing
   stuff.
5. Finally I write the RT to the backbuffer

Question:

- As you can see in the image below there's a problem with the
  boundingboxes. The are drawn using forward rendering and is drawn
  using the depthbuffer I descibed in step 2. I have tried to offset
  the depthbuffer in different directions with a texel or two. But
  nothing seems to solve the problem. Has anyone experienced this
  problem before?

**EDIT:**
   This post has been cleaned from some statements to avoid confusion.

[image]

Comment: That's a really strange problem, especially since it only happens at 1920x1080. Can you put a test case online to see if it's just your hardware or an XNA problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I was wrong. The source of the problem was in step 5 where I used a shader to copy the rendertarget to the backbuffer.

I forgot to correct the texture coordinates by negative texel X and Y. Not doing this results in incorrect sampling and color data being lost because the sample was taken at the wrong texel.